# Cannot able to set text box value using javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Any one please tell me how to set the value of textbox.

```
function moreFieldsEditFunction(ExtraFname, ExtraFvalue) {
    document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value =ExtraFvalue;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is not working

Comment: Did you tryied to use the server side ID ? Like `document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = ExtraFvalue;`. This will need to wait for the element to be created in DOM, so don't forget to attach this function to the event `onload`.

Comment: With the snippet above, you only declare the function that updates the `TextBox`. Also, you need to call the function in a place in your page where the `TextBox` has already appeared.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the HTML that is rendered.

Also have you tried using the F12 Toolbar and script debugger to work out what's happening?

Comment: I am calling the javascript function from c# for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             {

                 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>moreFieldsEditFunction('" + extraFieldName[i] + "','" + extraFieldValue[i] + "');</script>");
             }

Comment: Why cant you just set the value of the text box in the server side code instead of calling a JS function?

Comment: Regardless I suspect that the issue with what you have now is that your function is being called before the DOM has been fully loaded and the function is not available.

If you were using jQuery you would do something like $(document).ready(function(){ CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE });

However unless there is a really good reason for you to do what you are trying to do I suggest that you re-evaluate the way that you are setting the values in that text box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are a million milles off to be honest, I have taken your code and put it into a web form with a button that can be clicked to call the function and it works, without seeing your mark up it will be difficult to diagnose but it should look something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function moreFieldsEditFunction(ExtraFname, ExtraFvalue) {
            document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = ExtraFvalue;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <input type="button" onclick="moreFieldsEditFunction('TEST', 'TEST2')" value="Click Me" />    

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work.

Comment: I am calling my function from server side.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             {

                 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>moreFieldsEditFunction('" + extraFieldName[i] + "','" + extraFieldValue[i] + "');</script>");
             }

Comment: I am getting the arguments in javascript function.I checked it with using alert().But I cant able to set the value.

Comment: So if you put alert(ExtraFname) in your function you get the correct value displayed in the alert box?

If this is the case then we really need to see the HTML that is being generated, right click, view source, copy and paste... then we should be able to help.

Comment: <input type="text" id="TextBox1" value="" tabindex="0">

Comment: Need to see the Whole output, Could you update your question with all of the HTML that is generated?